# Typescript Object is possibly 'null' focusing using ref in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

typescript is still giving me error

Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

even though I do this

```
myRef && myRef.current && myRef.current.focus();
```

if I use

```
myRef?.current?.focus();
```

I got

```
Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: What is the type of `myRef`? (How did you declare it?)

Comment: post the type of `myRef`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you define your reference, you should specify what type it will be:

```js
const myRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
```

> *(Note that the above assumes you're using it like `<div ref={myRef}>` - if you're setting `myRef.current` manually, you need to specify the type as `<HTMLElement|null>`.*

Once you have done this, you should be able to use the following:

```js
myRef.current?.focus()
```

Note that you do not need to use the existential check on `myRef` - that will *always* be an object with a `current` property - that's how react's API works.

Comment: ah crap i hate typescript

Answer (score 2):

To make typescript silent and tell typescript you know what you are doing.
you can use `exclamation mark(!)` before the variable you know that it can be `null`.
Like in existing scenario if `"current"` can be null in some scenarios and you want that
typescript do not show error on it.

```
myRef.!current.focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by adding something like this

```
if(myRef.current) myRef.current.focus();
```

as just having `myRef.current?.focus();` doesn't work